# angularjs synchronise $request to update database before $request.query() is fired on index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, angularjs

My index view is pulling all the models from database before the update is carried out is there any way to make sure these actions are synchronised. the model is updated and shows up in index page after a refresh here is the code

```
app = angular.module('enterprise',["ngResource"])
 .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider','$httpProvider', ($routeProvider,$locationProvider,provider )->         
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
 provider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')

 $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: '<%=asset_path('list.html') %>', controller: AppCtrl})
 $routeProvider.when('/new', {templateUrl: '<%=asset_path('edit.html') %>', controller: NewCtrl})
 $routeProvider.when('/edit/:id', {templateUrl: '<%=asset_path('edit.html') %>', controller: EditCtrl})
 $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
]

app.factory "People", ["$resource",($resource)->
  $resource("/people/:id", {id:"@id"},{update: {method:"PUT"}}, {})
]


@AppCtrl=["$scope","People",($scope, People)->
$scope.crew = People.query()
]


@NewCtrl=["$scope","$location", "People",($scope, $location, People) ->
$scope.save = ->
  person = People.save($scope.person)
  $location.path("/")

]
 @EditCtrl=["$scope", "$location", "$routeParams","People",($scope, $location,  $routeParams, People)->
$scope.person = People.get({id:$routeParams.id})

$scope.save = ->
    person = People.get({id:$routeParams.id }
    , ->
       person.name =  $scope.person.name
       person.description = $scope.person.description
       person.$update()
    )
    $location.path("/")
```

]

any advice on ensuring model is updated before returning to index view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `$location.path("/")` in the `People` resource's callback function. [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) actions have success/failure callbacks.

Comment: Thanks that worked  person.$update($location.path("/")  it pays to read documentation properly